# Removing word wrap in csv file - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, word-wrap

I have data similar to the single record shown below in `users.csv` file [Linux environment]:

```
"1583787721","tusharmisra","tushar.misra@example.com","","","Ok
","https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/1583787721","","","2016-005T11:20:08.942Z","","","","","","active"
```

Here how I can remove the word wrap (line wrap?) in the CSV file using a bash script. I have at least 1000 records in `users.csv`.

Comment: Is it having fixed number of fields ?

Comment: yes having 16 fields.

Comment: So you have CSV records where a field enclosed in double quotes contains a newline (sometimes) and you want to remove the newline when it is the last character in the field, and replace it with a blank when it isn't the last character in the field?  It would help if you showed the expected output.  I also suspect the example isn't quite as minimal as it could be (so it isn't quite an MCVE ([MCVE])).  You could show an example with 6 fields instead of 16. with the split in the 3rd, or something.  Is it always the same field that's split, or could it be any of the fields?

Comment: Actually i was loading these data into table where the next line is considered as new row.

Comment: You want to use the `cut` command.

Comment: Do you want the input data to be treated as one record or two?  Show the expected output.  It's also helpful to show a few (say 2-5) shorter records worth of input and the expected output.

Comment: Is it possible that you have opened it in a text editor & that editor has word-wrapped the data?

Comment: when i opened same csv file in my windows machine .I can see the records in single line . But in linux due to this word wrap , next line is considered as new record .

Comment: I sincerely hope you are not posting email addresses of your real users in a public forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NF!=16&&!line{line=$0;next} NF!=16&&line{line=line $0} {n=split(line, a, ",")} n==16{print line;line=""}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gsed '/,"[^"][^"]*$/{N;s/\n//}' data.in >data.new
```

This GNU `sed` script will read from the file `data.in` and find any row that ends with `,"XXX`, where `XXX` can be any string not containing the `"` character. This indicates a wrapped row (in the sample that you provided).

When such a row is found, the next line of input is appended to it, and any newline in the concatenated row is removed.

The resulting line is outputted, as is any non-modified line.

The output is stored in `data.new`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on fixed # of fields you can use this awk:

```
awk -F '"[^"]+"' 'NF<15{s = s $0; next} s{print s; s=""} 1; END{if (s) print s}' file
```